# Error can't find hash method on custom key class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I have a inheritance structure that includes a base data class and a Dynamo Data class. I then try and use a custom class as an identifier. I declare everything as stated and yet it blows up cause it can't find the annotation of DynamoDBHashKey

I have tried running through a debugger. It goes through and finds the underlying annotation and method for the @DynamoDBHashKey. It then tries to do it again on the parent and fails with not existing on the parent class which it shouldn't exist. If I add the annotation to the key then it will say it is defined twice and error out. Note if I add @id for the SubmissionData object then it says the id field is defined twice.

```
public class BaseData<T>
{
    @Id
    protected T id;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "")
public class DynamoData<T> extends BaseData<T>
{
   ...
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@DynamoDBTable( tableName = "submission" )
public class SubmissionData extends DynamoData<SubmissionId>
{
    private SubmissionId id;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "locationNumber")
    public String getLocationNumber() {
        return getId().getLocationNumber();
    }

    public void setLocationNumber(String locationNumber) {
        getId().setLocationNumber(locationNumber);
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "createdDateMillis")
    public Long getCreatedDateMillis() {
        return getId().getCreatedDateMillis();
    }

    public void setCreatedDateMillis(Long createdDateMillis) {
        getId().setCreatedDateMillis(createdDateMillis);
    }

}

public class SubmissionId implements Serializable {
    private String locationNumber;
    private Long createdDateMillis;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    public String getLocationNumber() {
        return locationNumber;
    }

    public void setLocationNumber(String locationNumber) {
        this.locationNumber = locationNumber;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public Long getCreatedDateMillis() {
        return createdDateMillis;
    }

    public void setCreatedDateMillis(Long createdDateMillis) {
        this.createdDateMillis = createdDateMillis;
    }

}

public abstract class BasePersistence<S extends BaseData<ID>, ID, T extends CrudRepository<S, ID>>
{
    protected T repository;

    protected BasePersistence(T repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}

public abstract class DynamoPersistence<S extends DynamoData<V>, T extends CrudRepository<S, V>, V> extends BasePersistence<S, V, T>
{
    public DynamoPersistence(T repository)
    {
        super(repository);
    }
}

@Component
public class SubmissionPersistence extends DynamoPersistence<SubmissionData, SubmissionRepository, SubmissionId>
{
    @Autowired
    public SubmissionPersistence(SubmissionRepository repository)
    {
        super(repository);
    }
}

@EnableScan
public interface SubmissionRepository extends CrudRepository<SubmissionData, SubmissionId>
{
}
```

I would expect this should work but instead I get the following error stack:

````
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'submissionPersistence' defined in file [/Users/brett.yerger/cfacode/sc-inventory-scanner-api/target/classes/com/cfa/supplychain/invscan/component/submissions/persistence/SubmissionPersistence.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'submissionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method or field annotated by @DynamoDBHashKey within type java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'submissionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method or field annotated by @DynamoDBHashKey within type java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method or field annotated by @DynamoDBHashKey within type java.lang.Object!
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyMethodExtractorImpl.<init>(DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyMethodExtractorImpl.java:99) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.CompositeIdHashAndRangeKeyExtractor.<init>(CompositeIdHashAndRangeKeyExtractor.java:31) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.getHashAndRangeKeyExtractor(DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.java:71) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.<init>(DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.java:49) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.java:125) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:104) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getDynamoDBRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:128) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:150) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 77 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: Since I am using lombok I added this but made no difference:```    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private SubmissionId id```